# To change template through Ajax in Symfony

Tags: php, templates, symfony1

there are two templates i am using for view and edit(is having the form to update),
the view will contain edit(link or button), on clicking the edit button i want that the edit template should be loaded (using Ajax, without refreshing the page).
 and after editing it should be redirected to view again (using ajax same as above).
is there any code or method to do that? please help me...

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your whole content DIV with the result of the AJAX call. In the controller, check if the request is a XMLHTTP request. If so, only return the template without the layout around it.

So you don't change the template, you are just fetching the result of an action via AJAX.

Hava a look the documentation [integrating AJAX](http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_2/11-Ajax-Integration#chapter_11_ajax_helpers).

Answer (score 0):

You should also consider [in-place editing](http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_0/11-Ajax-Integration#chapter_11_sub_edit_in_place) if it'll fit into your design.

Comment: yeah, i tried that but not working... is there anything, that i should do in Action?? and in div what should i put the form or the data?? 
i saw this helper in many sites but i am confused...please help...

Comment: Is the front-end side of things not working or is the value not being changed in the database ?

Comment: the frontend is not working (hence didnot try the backend..)...and is there anything to do in the controller??

Comment: actually there are two templates, one which has the view(where we have the edit link/button), and on clicking edit the second template should open  i.e edit. where i want to do the edit and on saving it should be back to view template. [the edit template will contain the form element]

Comment: You've tried any methods like 
<?php echo input_in_place_editor_tag('edit_me', 'mymodule/myaction', array(
  'cols'        => 40,
  'rows'        => 10,
))

for in-place editing ?

Answer (score 0):

I think in-place-edit is best option here. I have used [jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) and jQuery in symfony to achieve similar functionality. Please have a look at http://myimalert.com/stock_alerts

I could not find native support for in-place-edit in Symfony 1.4.